# generating the right SOAP XML structure from a JAXB annotated class

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

**Generated from the ProcessRequestBean class listed at the end,

This is what I get:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cel="http://www.myweb.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <cel:processRequestOp>
        <processReq>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <serviceID> 1 </serviceID>
           <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
           <parameter>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <name> myname </name>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <value> myvalue </value>
           </parameter>
        </processReq>
    </cel:processRequestOp>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**But this is what I want:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cel="http://www.myweb.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <cel:processRequestOp>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <serviceID>1</serviceID>
             <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <parameter>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <name> myname </name>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <value> myvalue </value>
            </parameter>
        </cel:processRequestOp>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Note, the exta parent (processReq) element that is eliminated from this structure.**

**My SEI looks like this:**

```
@WebService(name="QueryThirdParty", targetNamespace = "http://www.myweb.com")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface QuerySEI {

public static final String targetNS = "http://www.myweb.com";

@WebMethod(operationName = "processRequestOp", action = "get_them")
@RequestWrapper(className =  "biz.webservice.query3rdpartyaccount.ProcessRequestBean", localName = "localName", partName = "partName")
@ResponseWrapper(className = "biz.webservice.query3rdpartyaccount.ProcessResponseBean")
@WebResult(partName = "processResp", name = "processRequestResponse")
public ProcessResponseBean getAccountNumbers(@WebParam(partName = "processReq", name = "ProcessRequestBean", mode = Mode.IN) ProcessRequestBean request);

}
```

**and ProcessRequestBean class looks like this:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "processRequest") //the name of the XML root element 
@XmlType(propOrder = {"serviceID", "parameter"})
public class ProcessRequestBean {

private String serviceID;

private List<RequestParameterElement> parameter;

public ProcessRequestBean(String serviceID, List<RequestParameterElement> parameter) {
    this.serviceID = serviceID;
    this.parameter = parameter;
}

public ProcessRequestBean() {
}

@XmlElement(name = "serviceId")//xml name of this property
public String getServiceID() {
    return serviceID;
}

public void setServiceID(String serviceID) {
    this.serviceID = serviceID;
}    

@XmlElement(name = "parameter")
public List<RequestParameterElement> getParameter() {
    return parameter;
}

public void setParameter(List<RequestParameterElement> parameter) {
    this.parameter = parameter;
}
}
```

**all help is appreciated**

Comment: So you want the <processReq> element gone? I think you can just remove `partName = "processReq"` from your `ProcessResponseBean` I am not sure if that will help you out. Also I see you add a lot of extra options to your SEI class. Allowing Netbeans to generate the web service class should have no problems with default SOAP client implementation.

Comment: @j.con doing this only changes the partName to ProcessRequestBean (the default). It does not get rid of that (processReq) element

Answer (score 0):

Please try following changes in ur SEI and ProcessRequestBean class,

**SEI**

```
@WebResult(partName = "processResp", name = "processRequestResponse")
public ProcessResponseBean getAccountNumbers(ProcessRequestBean request);

}
```

**ProcessRequestBean class**

get rid of @XmlRootElement(name = "processRequest") annotation..

```
      @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)    
      @XmlType(propOrder = {"serviceID", "parameter"})
public class ProcessRequestBean {

private String serviceID;

private List<RequestParameterElement> parameter;

public ProcessRequestBean(String serviceID, List<RequestParameterElement> parameter) {

......
......
......
```

Let me know if it doesn't resolve ur prblm.

Comment: 'name' and 'value' are children of 'parameter'. This way I dont get the 'parameter' element. You can throw some more light

Comment: Edited my answer. Add XmlAccessorType annotation in ur bean class, get rid of XmlRootElement annotation and remove webparam from ur sei.

Comment: I tried out your solution but unfortunately it eliminates <processReq></processReq> element and introduces the default <arg0></arg0> element as a replacement